# How to shift dates in a pandas dataframe (add x months)?

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns of dates.

I know how to shift dates by a fixed number of months (eg add 3 months to all the dates in column x); however, I cannot figure out how to shift dates by a number of months which is not fixed, but is another column of the dataframe.

Any ideas?

I have copied a minimal example below. The error I get is:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous
```

Thanks a lot!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['year'] = np.arange(2000,2010)
df['month'] = 3

df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(  (df.year * 10000 + df.month * 100 +1).apply(str), format='%Y%m%d')
df['month shift'] = np.arange(0,10)

# if I want to shift mydate by 3 months, I can convert it to DatetimeIndex and use dateOffset:
df['my date shifted by 3 months'] = pd.DatetimeIndex( df['mydate'] ) + pd.DateOffset(months = 3)

# however, how do I shift mydate by the number of months in the column 'month shift'?
#This does NOT work:
df['my date shifted'] = pd.DatetimeIndex( df['mydate'] ) + pd.DateOffset(months = df['month shift'])
print df
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want: `df['my date shifted'] = df['mydate'] + pd.TimedeltaIndex( df['month shift'], unit='M')`?

Comment: Could you add expected output?

Comment: @EdChum, your suggestion works, thanks a lot! However, why on Earth did your code work and mine didn't? is it documented anywhere, or is pandas' syntax just extremely capricious when it comes to dates? Comapred to Matlab and SQL, I simply cannot find any consistency in the syntax, nor in the documentation

Comment: I'm constructing a timedeltaindex and adding another series, `pd.DateOffset` only constructs a scalar `DateOffset` object it can't construct a Series. Note that for the 2nd row it makes the date `2001-03-31` which may not be what you want hence my question

Comment: Actually I hadn't noticed that. Is this because pandas converts 1 month to 30 days? Ideally no, I would need 1-Mar-2001 + 1 month to become 1-Apr-2001 ; these headings need to be precise as I need to group by them. Can your code be tweaked to get this result?

Comment: This is something that is missing at the moment AFAIK, interestingly this raises a warning `df['mydate'] + df['month shift'].apply(lambda x: pd.DateOffset(month=x))
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:450: PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting array of DateOffsets to Series not vectorized
  PerformanceWarning)` this shows that even if you did have an array of DateOffset it would still not be vectorised anyway currently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you could use `apply` with `axis=1`:

```
In [23]: df.apply(lambda x: x['mydate'] + pd.DateOffset(months = x['month shift']), axis=1)
Out[23]:
0   2000-03-01
1   2001-04-01
2   2002-05-01
3   2003-06-01
4   2004-07-01
5   2005-08-01
6   2006-09-01
7   2007-10-01
8   2008-11-01
9   2009-12-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but EdChum's solution seems faster; I guess this may be because running apply statements tends to be slow

Comment: My method is vectorised as it constructs an index and adds this to another series but it may not be what you want due to the `2001-03-31` as I've explained already

Comment: I see. Since my dataframe is not huge, I will use Anton's solution for now. I do wonder if there is a way to vectorise - make Anton's code faster when applying it to large dataframes. Guys, thanks a lot to you two both!

Answer (score 4):

"one"-liner using the [underlying numpy functionality](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic):

```py
df['my date shifted'] = (
    df["mydate"].values.astype("datetime64[M]") 
    + df["month shift"].values.astype("timedelta64[M]")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

EdChurn's solution is indeed much faster than the answer of Anton Protopopov and in fact in my use case it executes in milliseconds versus the one with apply taking minutes. The problem is that the solution EdChurn posted in his comment gives slightly incorrect results. In the example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['year'] = np.arange(2000,2010)
df['month'] = 3

df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime((df.year * 10000 + df.month * 100 + 1).apply(str), format='%Y%m%d')
df['month shift'] = np.arange(0,10)
```

The answer of:

```
df['my date shifted'] = df['mydate'] + pd.TimedeltaIndex( df['month shift'], unit='M')
```

gives:
[image: EdChurn solution]

The correct solution can be obtained with:

```
def set_to_month_begin(series):
    #Following doesn't work:
    #  res = series.dt.floor("MS")

    #This also doesn't work (it fails in case the date is already the first day of the month):
    #  res = series - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)

    res = pd.to_datetime(series).dt.normalize()
    res = res - pd.to_timedelta(res.dt.day - 1, unit='d')
    return res

def add_months(df, date_col, months_num_col):
    """This function adds the number of months specified per each row in `months_num_col` to date in `date_col`.
    This method is *significantly* faster than:
        df.apply(lambda x: x[date_col] + pd.DateOffset(months = x[months_num_col]), axis=1)
    """
    number_of_days_in_avg_month = 365.24 / 12
    time_delta = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df[months_num_col] * number_of_days_in_avg_month + 10, unit='D')
    return set_to_month_begin(df[date_col] + time_delta)

df['my date shifted'] = add_months(df, 'mydate', 'month shift')
```

This gives the following result:
[image: correct solution]