# function with date parameter to run on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe:

df =

```
 |date        months_left    amount
0|06/09/2019  34             150000
1|25/12/2019  23             70000
2|13/01/2020  7              85000
...
```

I want to define a function that takes a date parameter and runs through each row in the dataframe. It should add the months_left to the date in the dataframe and if the resulting date is over the parameter date mentioned in the function then in a new column the value should be 0, if it's under the parameter date then it should be the same amount. so ideally it would look something like this if the parameter in the function was 31/12/2021.

```
 |date        months_left    amount    new_amount
0|06/09/2019  34             150000    0
1|25/12/2019  23             70000     70000
2|13/01/2020  7              85000     85000
```

As for the first row the date added to the months_left goes over 31/12/2021 the resulting value is 0. The other rows don't go over 31/12/2021 so their amount isn't affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your `date` column is a datetime

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])  # note it is better to do this when you read the data
```

Then you can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59719009/1011724) to figure out if you are before the end date or not

```
end_date = datetime.date(2021, 12, 31)  # note you need to import datetime
past_end_date = (df.date.values.astype("datetime64[M]") + df.months_left.values.astype("timedelta64[M]")) > end_date
#  Note a pandas TimedeltaIndex might be an alternative to this numpy approach https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html
#  i.e. past_end_date = (df["date"] + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df["months_left"], unit="M")) > end_date
#  the answers will be a bit different on edge cases
```

and now do some indexing

```
df["new_amount"] = df["amount"]
df.loc[past_end_date, "new_amount"] = 0
```